# Regarding visibility over AWS Cost Explosion

Tags: amazon-web-services, billing, alerts

we are running AWS Infra with various services. We have configured Alarm for Daily budget as well as cost anomalies, but it seems all those comes based on 24 hrs frequency. We have ran into strange problem lost month. It seems there was a bug in our deployment that caused rapid spike in DYNAMODB utilization where the cost spiked thousands of dollar in one or two hours we only come to know at the end of the day where it burns extra thousands of dollars before we actually come to know the bug.

**What we are having**

we have configured alarms on cost explorer and also tried to check the cost usage based on Granularity with HOURLY but it seems the cost explorer API only keep updates once in every 6 hrs or even more, this was confirmed by AWS support.

**Expected solution:**

It would be nice we could have visibility over the cost utilization on hourly basis or at least in the interval of 2-3 hrs. I believe AWS cost explore or any service would help here. It would be great if some one could help us directing to the tool that will help us to achieve our use case or any recommendation to tackle this would be much appreciated.

Comment: If cost explorer doesn't give the granularity you need, why not simply monitor the services themselves for anomalies and set alarms against them? An unusual usage spike in DynamoDB which doesn't correspond to traffic patterns would be a good indicator of something going wrong.

Comment: In addition to what @chamal said, you might want to look into setting up a specific cloud spend monitoring solution such as Cloudability.